# Android native code in Codename One with lambda not working

Tags: java, android, codenameone

My App built with Codename One features a Camera preview. I need to resort to the Native Interface implementation (so far Android) to show this preview. On some (older) Android devices I also need to call `Camera.autofocus(AutofocusCallback)` to make a sharp preview.

Android studio suggests me to use lambda expression to define the callback :

```
mCamera.autoFocus((b, camera) -> Log.d(TAG, "Camera may have focused"));
```

When I debug my project it wortks.

However when I copy paste this piece of code in Codename One native interface implementation, and send the Android build, the build process fails with the following error :

```
error: ')' expected
            mCamera.autoFocus((b, camera) -> Log.d(TAG, "Camera may have focused"));
                                ^
error: illegal start of expression
            mCamera.autoFocus((b, camera) -> Log.d(TAG, "Camera may have focused"));
                                           ^
error: ';' expected
            mCamera.autoFocus((b, camera) -> Log.d(TAG, "Camera may have focused"));
```

To get the build I have to convert the lambda into the more traditional :

```
mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera may have focused");
                }
            });
```

Can't I use lambda in native interface implementation whereas it works flawlessly in Codename One code ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are are Java 8 feature. Is your codename one project a Java 8 project? The documentation suggests you have to explicitly enable Java 8 by setting "source" and "target" values in your build.xml to 1.8 as well as as set a build hint java.version=8. 
There are also some other suggestions checking which java version your ide uses:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html

Comment: Yes @Frank Lauterwald my project is a Java 8 project. And Lambda expressions are used in my Forms eg to define  the button actions. The build fails only when I use lambda in the native interface implementation.

Comment: This isn't currently implemented for native code so we won't break existing Android native code. However, the latest Android SDK's introduced a separate approach for using Java 8 (this came well after we introduced Java 8 support) so we added build hints to try and enable this support, this isn't tested and will only be available this Friday you can try it with the `android.java8=true` build hint and let us know if it works or doesn't

Comment: Thanks @Shai I'll keep you posted as soon as I've tested this new build hint!

Comment: In CodenameOne Settings window I added the key "android.java8" with value "true" and added the lambda codes but received `/build.gradle': 64: unexpected token: } @ line 64, column 1.
     }` while sending the build. If I remove the build hint and let the lambda codes it does not compile because of the error depicted in my original question, and if eventually I remove the lambdas, it compiles well. So I guess the key/value is not entered as expected one, is it ?